# Cancel image requests for disposed items flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a large list with about 100+ items in a grid of 3, and they all have a [`cached_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) in them.

Whenever I scroll the list a little fast, the images start to load. But if I keep scrolling, all the image requests are still active, so I'd reach the end of the list with 100+ image requests still active, even though those widgets are now disposed.

I tried contacting the developers of the package, and all they said was that yes, they do not cancel requests, which is not helpful at all.

Is there any way I can cancel those requests? Or at least sone way to save the app from suddenly crashing?

Comment: What is the crash you are seeing?

Comment: can you provide some reproducible example?

Comment: check `ScrollAwareImageProvider` - the docs say: *"An ImageProvider that makes use of Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext to avoid loading images when rapidly scrolling."*

Comment: @pskink I tried using that, and I'm not seeing any difference. Even if the context is cancelled, that won't cancel the network request

Comment: @pskink My issue isn't when scrolling fast, it's when scrolling slightly fast. The image request would start in the few milli seconds the widget is visible, but it won't get cancelled (when returning, the image is there, and in the network monitor it's complete)

Comment: so you can customize when to start loading images by providing a custom scroll physics, more here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/recommendDeferredLoading.html

Comment: any solutions in this case?